# Is there any possibility to display the gini-impurity (or information gain) in rpart.plot?

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree, gini

I would like to see the gini-impurity on each node in rpart.plot, like in python:

https://miro.medium.com/max/2408/1*aBIvTfp5gZ2F0ZSHbd3DSQ.png

vs

[image]

Is there any possibility to display the gini-impurity (or information gain) in rpart.plot?